# Webpage Cannot be found when trying to start a workflow for one user

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, permissions

I am trying to manually kick off a workflow from SharePoint, it give me the open to select the workflow but when it is about to load the Start and Cancel option to start the workflow, i receive a The Webpage cannot be found. The permissions are set as full control. I have gotten someone else to log into share point on my PC an they receive the option to Start and Cancel the workflow.

This is the page which i receive:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the list where workflow is associated --> List Settings --> Advanced Settings: Under Item-level permissions --> Read access ensure that Read all items is selected.

Comment: Hi @hursh Gupta still the same thing is happening :(

Comment: If this is happening only for your user id, I suggest you also add yourself as a Site Collection Admin and even cross check what permissions the other users have who can access the workflow well.

Comment: it is happening with any user who did not create the workflow in sharepoint designer